# Does the Lenovo LT3053p monitor have the same overshoot problems as the Dell u3014?

Tags: display

Both the Lenovo LT3053p and the Dell u3014 monitors are based on the same LG AH-IPS panel.  The Dell monitor has [significant](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/peripherals/f/3529/t/19526164.aspx) [overshoot](http://hardforum.com/showthread.php?t=1754377) [problems](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/peripherals/f/3529/t/19499353.aspx) in some circumstances due to RTC overdrive. My question is whether the Lenovo has the same issue.

If you have access to an LT3053p to test on, I've found a good way to detect this problem is with the color temperature filter [F.Lux](http://www.justgetflux.com).  Turn that on, then go to a page with black on a white background.  Due to flux it'll be more of a slightly reddish off-white background.  I've found xkcd.com shows the effect well on the u3014.  Then scroll the page.  If there is an overshoot problem, you should notice what appears to be a green afterimage shadowing the black portions as you scroll.

Answer (score 0):

From the PRAD review, it appears that overdrive is indeed a problem with the LT3053p.  The review is still behind a paywall, but [this summary](http://translate.google.ca/translate?hl=en&sl=de&u=http://www.pressebox.de/%3Fboxid%3D624510&prev=/search%3Fq%3Dprad%2Blt3053p%2Btest%26client%3Dfirefox-a%26hs%3DFBU%26rls%3Dorg.mozilla:en-US:official) mentions the overshoot problem.